# PrimennGTreeTable Icon not visible

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular5, primeng

I am using PrimeNG TreeTable,but In my below code expand/collapse Icon is not visible, 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable

I don't know if the problem is with rowNode,

I am getting only Parent data,children data are not visible because collapse/expand icon is not visible

```
 <p-treeTable [value]="files2">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-expanded="expanded" >
        <tr>
            <td (click)="toggle()" >
                 <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" ></p-treeTableToggler> 
                {{rowData.name}}
            </td>
            <td>{{rowData.size}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.type}}</td>
        </tr>            
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

ts file

```
     this.files2=[  
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Applications",
                "size":"200mb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[  
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Angular",
                        "size":"25mb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"angular.app",
                                "size":"10mb",
                                "type":"Application"
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"cli.app",
                                "size":"10mb",
                                "type":"Application"
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"mobile.app",
                                "size":"5mb",
                                "type":"Application"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"editor.app",
                        "size":"25mb",
                        "type":"Application"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"settings.app",
                        "size":"50mb",
                        "type":"Application"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

Here I am getting only parent values, I am not getting children values

Comment: `"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10", "primeng": "^6.1.4"`, I have these, I double-triple checked my config, the whole stuff is a fresh project and toggler is not displayed.

Comment: I found what is the problem. It seems if there is no `children` property, then toggler is not displayed. I haven't checked the source code so far for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In treetable primeng used `primeicons` so you need to install it before use

```
npm install primeicons --save

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />
```

For more information you can refer startup guide here -

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Comment: but in primeng version 6.0.0, all the icons are not working

Comment: they must changed some configuration, do read the documentation

Comment: Primeng guys have updated fa icon to fa fa icon, but wherever I have inbuilt class as  fa, how to change that as fa fa

Comment: It worked for me with 6.0.0, I configured it with angular CLI.